# Can I reduce my instances count to ZERO during silent hours through AutoScaling?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've started exploring Amazon's ElasticBeanstalk (along with other cloud providers like Google Cloud) as a potential expansion point for one of my new apps.

However, since I have the tendency of launching multiple ideas in parallel, many of which generate little to no traffic in the beginning (e.g. to test drive a given new market, before dropping or investing effort into the product itself), I was wondering if Amazon Web Services allows some way of minimizing the costs of such trial products during the periods when it doesn't receive traffic, and only spin on instances when it actually starts receiving traffic.

In other words, can I reduce the MinInstanceCount somehow to ZERO, so that Amazon spins up new containers as soon as the app starts receiving traffic, and shut down the instances (and the related billing aggregation) when it stops - without manual intervention.

I know that Google's AppEngine offers this model where you are not billed for a container until it's actually receiving traffic (as soon as the traffic stops - the container is killed). I am just wondering if AWS provides such a thing.

Answer (score 3):

AppEngine is a very different type of service. I would compare Google App Engine to AWS Lambda instead of EC2.

Unfortunately, if you waited until you started receiving traffic to spin up an EC2 instance it would be too late to process that traffic. It usually takes a few minutes for an EC2 instance to start up, and during that time all incoming traffic would receive error responses from the Load Balancer due to there being no healthy instances in the pool.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that your idea largely depends on the type of application you have, but one thing to note is that AWS uses a **price per hour** model vs Google Cloud which charges you **per 15 minutes** of usage. This means that unless you are keeping your nodes turned off for multiple hours at a time, you will not see drastic cost savings. If you do plan on keeping your nodes off for days at a time, I would suggest using [AWS Data Pipeline](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-concepts-schedules.html) to schedule your nodes downtime. Pipeline allows you to run AWS Cli commands without managing access keys on either a schedule or based on activation.

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce "Minimum Group Size" and "Desired" parameters to zero. But since there won't be any instances that could make a CloudWatch alarm raised, Autoscaling Group won't create instances for you. You will have to start them manually. But you can use this technique to automatically shutdown unused instances.